# Can I create a mutable array on Saxon's XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I know that an immutable array on XSLT 3.0 can be created as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
    <Item>a</Item>
    <Item>b</Item>
    <Item>c</Item>
</xsl:variable>
```

Also, that is it possible to create a mutable variable using Saxon's assign function:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="'val'" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
```

Is it possible to combine the two? i.e. creating a mutable array that allows editing individual items?

Note that due to some technical restrictions I am to use only XSLT/Saxon functions, so JavaScript is off the table, unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it? The feature of assignable variables is not recommended and you should try to use accumulators, iterators, higher-order functions and other standard language features. But I am not aware that the features has been witthdrawn from PE or EE. What is the use case you want to implement? Are you aware that there are functions to manipulate arrays in XSLT 3 or XPath 3.1? Technically the return a new array but of course that allow you to use the `$array` variable for some transformation and manipulate items in the sense of a functional language.

Comment: I have just noted that you have declared `xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*"` so you do not even have an array there in the sense of XSLT and XPath 3 but a sequence of element nodes. As with the previous comment, it seems you might want to first explain why you think you need a mutable array (or sequence?), i.e. which task you want to solve with standard XSLT 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a mutable variable is a quite different thing from having a variable that contains a mutable value. The only way you can create a mutable value in Saxon is to use an external Java object.

But why would you want to? Tell us what you want to achieve, and we can help you achieve it using XSLT the way it was designed to be used, working with the language rather than fighting against it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We are working with a problematic input XML file, that due to its structure forces us to collect data that is needed later in a manner of an array of counters. The counters have to be mutable (incrementing per each relevant node), and the array - dynamic in size, because of a variation in the required number of counters

Comment: I'm sure that a functional solution to the problem is possible but it's hard to know what it is when you only describe a procedural solution to the problem, rather than actually describing the problem.

Comment: @RoeeVakrat, it sounds as if accumulators or tunnel parameters would allow you to collect and pass on values in XSLT 2 or 3. But it is hard to tell without some sample data and the desired output and an explanation of which values you want to collect and where you need them. Your previous sample of a sequence of elements nodes have letters like `a` or `b` certainly doesn't seem to be an array of counters.